# Failed to boot Window 7 after installing Ubuntu 12.04: invalid EFI file path

Tags: installation, boot, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu alongside window 7 by following the instructions on the internet . I can use Ubuntu successfully. But I failed to boot Window 7.

I got this error:  invalid EFI file path.

I was looking at other similar posts. They mentioned something like ""Window  UEFI", which I have no idea what is means.

Please can someone tell me how to boot Window 7 again without losing everything on Win 7.

UPDATE: I reboot my laptop again. I pressed F2  / F10 to launch boot manager. I changed the boot option: 
boot option #1: Window blablabla
boot option #2: Ubuntu blablabla
boot option #3: Ubuntu blablabla

Then Suddenly I was able to launch Win 7 again. The weird thing was that it ran a disk scan / file scan after I logged onto my Win7 account. And I was prompted to format the local disk (:E) , which was where i installed my Ubuntu.

I am very puzzled now. Why cant I launch Win 7 in GRUB, but I can do so after rearranging the Win 7 boot option. Should I really consider removing Ubuntu, since I am worried I am going to lose my Win 7 again ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a newer computer with UEFI (and BIOS)?

Many then have Windows in BIOS mode, but when booting Ubuntu the UEFI/BIOS may boot in either UEFI or BIOS mode and install in that mode.

Or a few Windows 7 systems were installed in UEFI mode and you installed Ubuntu in BIOS mode.

Either way, to dual boot from grub menu both systems have to be either UEFI or both BIOS.

Best to see details and Boot-Repair can convert a BIOS install of Ubuntu to UEFI or vice-versa. You cannot easily convert Windows from its current install.

Post the link to the BootInfo report that this creates. Is part of Boot-Repair:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot.:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

You can repair many boot issues with this or 'Create BootInfo' report (Other Options) & post the link it creates, so we can see your exact configuration and diagnose advanced problems.